# Remove osx partition

Tags: partitioning, windows, macosx, refit

I triple boot OSx, Windows 8, and Ubuntu on an Imac. I rarely use the OSx and only boot into Windows to play some video games on occasion. my question is what is the process for removing OSx and giving the free space to Ubuntu with out wrecking my boot up? I should also mention that I have rEFit installed on the osx side so I'm not sure how that would work with osx gone..

Answer (score 1):

A default rEFIt installation goes in the OS X root (`/`) partition, so deleting that partition will also delete rEFIt.

The safest thing for you to do is nothing. Triple-boot setups like yours on Macs are *very* delicate, and attempting to mess with them is asking for trouble. If you need the disk space, it's better to add a new disk than to try messing with what you've got. If that's out of the question, though, the safest way to proceed is as follows:

1. Either re-install rEFIt to the EFI System Partition (ESP) or install the newer [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) there. Doing this is documented but not supported for rEFIt, and both documented and supported (but not recommended) for rEFInd. (The problem is that some Macs suffer from a ~30-second delay when booting rEFIt or rEFInd from the ESP.)
2. Test the above to be sure that rEFIt/rEFInd is working acceptably from the ESP. If you have problems, back out by re-installing rEFIt or rEFInd to the OS X root partition.
3. In Linux, use `mkfs` on the OS X partition. For instance, if it's `/dev/sda2` in Linux, you could use `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda2`.
4. Optionally, us `gdisk` to change the type code for the partition from AF00 to 8300. Linux doesn't really care about this, but if you subsequently boot OS X (even as an emergency disk), this should keep OS X from doing something nasty to the partition.

At this point, you should be able to use the new space for user files. Most desktop environments will present it as an empty disk device that they'll auto-mount somewhere under `/media`. Alternatively, you could mount the partition wherever you like by creating an entry in `/etc/fstab`. If you need to store system files, you'll need to boot into an emergency system, mount your main system somewhere, mount the new partition somewhere convenient, move files, create an `/etc/fstab` entry, and reboot.

A still more radical option is to use `gdisk` to convert the disk from GPT to MBR and begin treating the computer like a conventional BIOS-based machine. This may be cleaner in the long run if you want to use nothing but BIOS-mode OSes, but it's riskier in the short term. You could end up with something that won't boot until you re-install GRUB or make other repairs. You would *not* use rEFIt or rEFInd in such a configuration, just GRUB. Once the conversion is done, you can do the type of filesystem conversion I've described on it.